# Cannot run Project ASP when configs IIS on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, iis

I have a problem.
I had start a new simple website by Visual Studio 2013 look like this
File -> New -> Project -> Web -> Visual Studio 2012 -> ASP.NET Web Forms Application.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWO2R.png
Then I wrote code to calculate 
It ran well on Visual Studio.

But when I coppied it to IIS, I ran it, the website show the problems look like this
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hbk0.png

I was browsing but cannot found any answer to solved it. 
I also turned on IIS on Windows 8.1.
Please help me.

Comment: Read the error in the second screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the app pool has the correct .net clr version and the managed pipeline is the correct one (usually integrated). 
(start + R -> inetmgr -> Application Pools -> probably DefaultAppPool)